# Time of Day Calculation Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a script that downloads files from a site each day. There is one file per day and a new file is added 16:00. The file names use year, month date in title of file so I use that to know which files to get.

I am trying write in my script that if the current time today is before 4pm then find:

```
year = 2020

month = 4

day = 15
```

But if it is past 4pm then find:

```
year = 2020

month = 4

day = 16
```

I have tried:

```
timerightnow = datetime.now()
today4pm = timerightnow.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

But then doing `timerightnow < today4pm` gives me a syntax error?

Any ideas would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Acutally all solved! Will post the code

Comment: Please convert this to the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering the solution:

```
 timerightnow = datetime.now()
    today4pm = timerightnow.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

    if timerightnow < today4pm:
        year = timerightnow.year
        month = timerightnow.month
        day = timerightnow.day -1
    else:
        year = timerightnow.year
        month = timerightnow.month
        day = timerightnow.day
```